# Implement ResearchKit in a ViewController to make a survey

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

**EDIT:** Not sure if this may be the root of my issue, but would this piece of code in the app delegate be a reason why this is not working?

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let navigationController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! HomeViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    return true

}
```

I am trying to add survey functionality to an app with integration of ResearchKit. I have worked through the setup guide and some other tutorials from  Ray Wenderlich.  However when I transitioned into an app I would like to develop I got a bit stuck.

**I am getting thrown an error:** `Cannot assign value of type 'HomeviewController to type 'ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate?'`

**This is the code I am working with:**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

@IBAction func surveyTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: SurveyTask, taskRunUUID: nil)
    taskViewController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(NewRideViewController) {
        if let newRideViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NewRideViewController {
            newRideViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
        }
    }
}
}
```

Based on similar questions with this error syntax, users have added another controller class, but which one is beyond me.  Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you StackExchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not extended you view controller to implement delegate of `ORKTaskViewController` which is `ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate` and your VC code should be as follow  -

```
import ResearchKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func surveyTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: SurveyTask, taskRunUUID: nil)
        taskViewController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension HomeVC: ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {

    func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and provide code! I have added what you suggested and when I click the _survey_ button the app terminates and gives a _Thread 1: signal SIGABRT_ error, the debug console provides the following message:


 _Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Each step should have a unique identifier'_ 


I thought it may be the connections I have deleted the outlets and code and re-added the outlets correctly.  Do you have any idea why this error gets thrown?

Comment: Never mind, sorted through the debugger output and found the culprit.  Thank your for your assistance!